# Issues creating a glint or shine on a logo in After Effects that is exportable to HTML

Tags: adobe-after-effects, plugin

I am trying to replicate a moving logo with a glint that is exportable to HTML.

I followed this [video](https://youtu.be/6zJea9fWPik) which uses light sweep, the animation is working, but no light effects came through.

I read that Bodymovin does not support effects, so I used alpha matte instead to achieve the same effect as per this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1kX875V_7iw) but its still having problems. The light is showing up, but there is no matting, please see the image attached.

In summary, I am trying to make a logo with a glint/lightsweep effect that can work with Bodymovin. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to get either of these projects to work? Here is the [after effects project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvj8h.jpg) showing the look I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per [Bodymovin documentation](https://aescripts.com/bodymovin/), these are the supported features:

> - Shapes
>
>   - paths, ellipses, stars, rectangles
>   - fills, stroke, gradient fills and gradient strokes
>   - dashes
>   - trim paths (partial)
>   - rounded corners
>   - transforms (position, anchor point, rotate, scale, opacity, skew, skew axis)
> - Solids
> - Images
> - Comps
> - Nulls
> - Texts
>
>   - Most fonts are supported, they can be exported as shapes or as text provided you load the font on the browser
>   - A single text declination is supported per textbox.
>   - Not supported: text decorations like Small caps, or Vertical Scale.
> - Cameras (partial)
> - Expressions
>
>   - Expressions. Partially supported. More and more expressions are supported on each release.
>   - If you have any trouble with one, let us know.
>   - Expression sliders are supported.
> - General supported properties
>
>   - transform (rotate,scale,position,anchor point, opacity)
>   - time remap
>   - masks (additive, and in some cases difference, inverted and subtractive)
>   - luma and alpha masks (with the svg renderer)
> - Supported effects (with the svg/html renderer)
>
>   - fill
>   - pro levels
>   - drop shadow
>   - tint
>   - tritone

So as long as you use vector shapes and vector effects / transformations you should be good. Try using a vector mask and your glint could be another vector shape moving from side to side.